# Can I version a path in git whose name is operating system dependent

Tags: windows, macos, git, unix, vim

I wish to store my Mac, Windows and Linux vim configuration files in git. On *nix systems, your vim configuration files go in ${HOME}/.vim but for the Windows binary, the same directory is named "vimfiles" Can I configure git to accommodate the different directory name?

Comment: The names of the directories containing your repositories are not important as long as they all point to the same remote repo. So, basically you don't have to configure anything.

Comment: Actually, they're peer directories, i.e.,:
> ~/.git  
> ~/.vim  

If I place .git inside .vim|vimfiles how do I version the .vimrc|_vimrc in the parent directory?

Comment: Do you mean that you have put your whole `$HOME` under version control? I have a `~/.vim/vimrc` and `runtime vimrc` in my `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: @romainl yes and no. I'm using info/exclude to only include .vim and .vimrc. Interestingly, I never considered putting .vimrc IN the .vim folder, but this SE discussion here throws water on the idea: http://superuser.com/questions/438343/put-vimrc-into-the-vim-folder I don't want to symlink or do post-pull/push scripting.

Comment: No symlink or hooks here. My `~/.virmc` is a normal file with only one line: `runtime vimrc`: all the fun happens inside the `~/.vim` folder.

Comment: OK, I _think_ I like this suggestion. The only downside is manually setting up the .vimrc/_vimrc but that's really trivial overall. I like this alot; thanks!

Comment: It's only one line, the same for each platform, in one file. It's so quick and trivial, I wouldn't even call it "setting up something". It shouldn't take more time than writing this comment.

Comment: @romainl: We have a winner. I can't mark your suggestion as the answer, though?

Comment: I've made it into a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My setup is very simple.

On Mac, the versioned directory is:

```
/Users/username/.vim
```

On Linux, it is:

```
/home/username/.vim
```

On Windows XP (yes), it is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\vimfiles
```

They all point to the same GitHub repository.

My settings are stored in a `vimrc` (no `.` or `_`) file located at the root of the repository. Therefore its versioned and commited/pushed/pulled like all the rest.

The actual default user-specific `vimrc`,

```
/Users/username/.vimrc
/home/username/.vimrc
C:\Documents and Settings\username\_vimrc
```

is a real file, no need for a symlink. It contains only one line:

```
runtime vimrc
```

that tells vim to read, and execute, my `vimrc`.

Because of how `:runtime` works, I don't need to use a real absolute path which would be different on Unix-like platforms and on Windows.

Setting up a new machine or user is as simple as cloning my repo and typing two easy to remember words.

Comment: For the curious, @romainl and I step through this in my original question. Thanks!

Comment: Just did this. I used it to coordinate my vim install between cygwin and the Win32 binary. **RECOMMENDED** Next up is my mac and ubuntu, not expecting any problems.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to configure Git, just tell Vim to use `~/.vim` for Windows, too, by putting the following fragment into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" On Windows, also use '.vim' instead of 'vimfiles'; this makes synchronization
" across (heterogeneous) systems easier.
if has('win32') || has('win64')
    set runtimepath=$HOME/.vim,$VIM/vimfiles,$VIMRUNTIME,$VIM/vimfiles/after,$HOME/.vim/after
endif
```

Comment: Couldn't you just make a shortcut/symlink?

Comment: Ingo: interesting. I didn't say initially, but in cygwin, I'm good; vim uses the correct .vim directory. For the Windows non-cygwin binary, it can not read a .vimrc file, can it?

Comment: @KyleSkrinak According to the doc 1. vim tries reading `.vimrc` after `_vimrc` (`:h VIMINIT`). 2. vim does not have `~/.vim` in runtimepath on windows by default (`:h 'runtimepath'`). And it should be able to read this file, but AFAIR you will just have problems with creating it with some windows native software. And maybe with reading also.

Comment: Make sure that snippet is early in your vimrc. It must come before pathogen or anything else that manages plugins!

Answer (score 1):

I also need to share config files for vim and other applications between multiple systems, and I found that git was not only overkill but also required manual syncing on each system to get the latest updates and to publish changes.  A better solution for me is to put these config files into Dropbox, make all of my systems connect to my Dropbox account, and create symbolic links to these shared files.

For example, I put my vimrc file under `Dropbox/conf/vimrc`, and then did

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/conf/vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

You should be able to use Windows' `mklink` to similar effect to create a `_vimrc` symlink to that same file.  In the same way, a common `Dropbox/conf/vim` directory could be linked to locally as `.vim` or `.vimfiles` or whatever your OS' vim executable prefers.

Dropbox keeps a history of changes over the last 30 days, which is enough to handle recovering from most problems for which I needed git.  The cool thing is that you can add that new macro or setting to your `.vimrc` and it is automatically available on all your systems.

Of course this approach is also handy for your other config files, too (`.gitconfig`, `.gitignore`, `.bashrc`, etc.).

Comment: There's much to like in this suggestion. I see two quibbling downsides: 1) I like hosting my dot files on github for the public sharing aspects; even if I'm more of a consumer than producer for sharing info and 2) my .vim files are fairly stable, so I don't frequently push/pull for updates; maybe quarterly? Thanks!